# PHP templating javascript best practices?

Tags: javascript, php, templates, standards

What are some of the best practices for templates in PHP (Twig, etc) with JavaScript? Is it good/bad practice to include JavaScript within these templates? How should JavaScript be handled?

For example; a current setup that I have is

```
something.php
something.thtml // includes all templating and JavaScript
```

I was thinking maybe something like:

```
something.php
something.thtml // no JS
something.js // move index.thtml JS out and into its own JS file which is loaded.
```

However, this can become "spaghetti" in the long run; so I'm wondering what really is a good standard to follow when creating templates in PHP for easy maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/).

Example of a Twig template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="navigation">
        {% for item in navigation %}
            <li><a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.caption }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <h1>My Webpage</h1>
        {{ a_variable }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

normally your js would be separate from your html files anyway, so you should try to avoid putting any javascript in template file, but there is nothing wrong with doing so.

there should really be something like a public folder that holds your css, images, and js
then all HTML or templates are delivered separately

Comment: i would use multiple files and break them up by section, not sure what your project entails, but could probably break it up in to categories, then you could something like require.js to handle too many calls and to make sure your dependencies are in order

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's many different solid ways to do that, but I find that having different roles for each file is best.

I find it better to create the html header and footer in the php scripts, where you can call whatever javascript you wish

```
function makeHTML($vTitle,$vMetaKeywords,$vMetaDescription,$vJavascripts,$vOnLoad,$vPage)
 {$vHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html">' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<html>' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<head>' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<title>' . $Title . '</title>' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<LINK HREF="css/style.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">';
  $vHTML.= ($vJavascripts == '' ? '' : $vJavascripts);
  $vHTML.= '</head>' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '<body' . ($vOnLoad == '' ? '' : ' onLoad="' . $vOnLoad . '"') . '>' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= $vPage;
  $vHTML.= '</body>' . "\n";
  $vHTML.= '</html>' . "\n";
  return $vHTML;}
```

$vPage is the page you created from your templates, not containing any javascript nor html header.
that way you can work your header without having to modify all your templates

$vJavascripts contains the javascript you wish from any javascript file you may want.

this way you can work on your header or javascript without having to do it in fifteen different folders each time.

then, at the very end of your scripts, just echo $vHTML to page